# Overlay pushpins on maps Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, maps, pushpin

I am building an universal app for Windows where i am using maps control for displaying few hundreds of pushpins on map. In WinRT i successfully used Bing maps SDK and it works perfectly as i wish.
Problems coming out in my Windows phone project. There is no Bing maps for windows phone, so i am using build-in maps in wp sdk. Main problem in this restriction from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn792121.aspx#showing_xaml_controls_and_shapes_on_the_map):

`The MapIcon is not guaranteed to be shown. It may be hidden when it obscures other elements or labels on the map.`

This is unacceptable for my case, i want my pushpins overlay all others items on the map(including others pushpins), so user could see them all at the start of applications. I already tried to use ZIndex and all advices from the google, but nothing helped for me.

Did anyone solve this problem or can give me some advice to workaround this restriction?

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is using XAML children of the Map, e.g.

```
<maps:MapControl>
    <TextBox x:Name="MapOverlay" Text="Test" maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding FooLocationBinding}"/>
</maps:MapControl>
```

(`MapControl.Location` is an attached property which can also be set from the code behind if you won't be taking advantage of bindings.)